# How to Recover Deleted Top Site from Microsoft Edge

Tags: browser, microsoft-edge

After accidentally deleting a top site from the suggested top sites we see when opening a new tab on Microsoft Edge, I can no longer make this website become visible again.

I use this site several times a day, but it stills do not appear again there.

How can I recover this site?

Answer (score 0):

Two things happened when you removed it from the list:

1. It got removed from the list (duh!)
2. It was added to a list of site not to appear as part of frequent sites (huh?)

So you would want to reverse step 2. Unfortunately, the only way (I know of) is to remove it from the registry:

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppContainer\Storage\microsoft.microsoftedge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge\TabbedBrowsing\NewTabPage\Exclude
```

Just delete the entries for exclude. If you are not comfortable with RegEdit, I suggest you don't do it yourself or ask someone you trust to do it.